# Printing Single Quote inside the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, quoting

I want to output

```
XYZ's "ABC"
```

I tried the following 3 statements in Python IDLE.

- 1st and 2nd statement output a `\` before `'`.
- 3rd statement with print function doesn't output `\` before `'`.

Being new to Python, I wanted to understand why `\` is output before `'` in the 1st and 2nd statements.

```
>>> "XYZ\'s \"ABC\""
'XYZ\'s "ABC"'

>>> "XYZ's \"ABC\""
'XYZ\'s "ABC"'

>>> print("XYZ\'s \"ABC\"")
XYZ's "ABC"
```

Comment: This has been explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052654/python-string-adding-backslash-before-single-quotes

Comment: Being new to python, i just wanted to understand the difference. I have edited the question and @SorousH answer explains it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my observations when you call `repr()` on a string: (It's the same in IDLE, REPL, etc)

- If you print a string(a normal string without single or double quote) with `repr()` it adds a *single* quote around it. (**note**: when you hit enter on REPL the `repr()` gets called not `__str__` which is called by `print` function.)
- If the word has **either** `'` or `"` : First, there is no backslash in the output. The output is gonna be surrounded by `"` if the word has `'` and `'` if the word has `"`.
- If the word has **both** `'` and `"`: The output is gonna be surrounded by *single quote*. The `'` is gonna get escaped with backslash but the `"` is not escaped.

Examples:

```py
def print_it(s):
    print(repr(s))
    print("-----------------------------------")

print_it('Soroush')
print_it("Soroush")

print_it('Soroush"s book')
print_it("Soroush's book")

print_it('Soroush"s book and Soroush\' pen')
print_it("Soroush's book and Soroush\" pen")
```

output:

```
'Soroush'
-----------------------------------
'Soroush'
-----------------------------------
'Soroush"s book'
-----------------------------------
"Soroush's book"
-----------------------------------
'Soroush"s book and Soroush\' pen'
-----------------------------------
'Soroush\'s book and Soroush" pen'
-----------------------------------
```

So with that being said, the only way to get your desired output is by calling `str()` on a string.

- <sub>I know `Soroush"s book` is grammatically incorrect in English. I just want to put it inside an expression.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want it to print.
Do you want it to output `XYZ\'s \"ABC\"` or `XYZ's "ABC"`?

The `\` escapes next special character like quotes, so if you want to print a `\` the code needs to have two `\\`.

```
string = "Im \\" 
print(string)
```

Output: `Im \`

If you want to print quotes you need single quotes:

```
string = 'theres a "lot of "" in" my "" script'
print(string)
```

Output: `theres a "lot of "" in" my "" script`

Single quotes makes you able to have double quotes inside the string.