# Glue string adds double quotations or backslashes which throws error in database query

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, r-glue

How do I return a string with only single quotes from the `glue::glue_sql` command? I have tried two different approaches:

**Approach 1**

```
con <- RAthena::dbConnect(RAthena::athena(),
                 s3_staging_dir = s3_staging_dir)

column_values <- c("thing1","thing2","thing3")

query1 <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ({column_values*})", .con = con)
query1
```

This returns:

```
'SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN (\'thing1\', \'thing2\', \'thing3\')'
```

**Approach 2**

```
con <- RAthena::dbConnect(RAthena::athena(),
                 s3_staging_dir = s3_staging_dir)

column_values <- c("thing1","thing2","thing3")

query2 <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ({`column_values`*})", .con = con)
query2
```

this returns:

```
'SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ("thing1", "thing2", "thing3")'
```

**My desired output**

```
"SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')"
```

Comment: The use of single-quotes or double-quotes is DBMS-specific, but I believe that Athena uses single-quotes for string literals; because of this I think your approach 1 is correct, and approach 2 is wrong since double-quotes do not define string literals. What happens when you send approach 1 to the database?

Comment: I get `Error: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:86: Column 'thing1' cannot be resolved`

However I think the issue is coming from me using R in a jupyterlab notebook. When I run the same command in rstudio everything looks fine. Don't know how to resolve this issue...

Comment: Gotcha. I have no experience with jupyterlab, unfortunately, but I've added the tag, hope somebody else can provide insight.

Answer (score 0):

Name your vector:

```
col_val <- c(t1 = "thing1", t2 = "thing2", t3 = "thing2")
```

Then use the `{vars*}` syntax:

```
query3 <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ({col_val*})", .con = con)
query3 

<SQL> SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing2')
```

Edit: see discussion below - this appears to be local to me and NOT a good answer to the question.

Comment: What does adding names to `col_val` do here? How is your `col_val` different from the OP's `column_values`? When I run your code with and without names in `col_val`, there is no difference in the output.

Comment: As I stated in my comment above, The real issue is doing this in jupyterlab. Perhaps a different question altogether.

Comment: @r2evans when It tested this I was getting different outputs depending on named or unnamed variables.  I'll have a poke around and see if I can figure out why.  If it's not happening at your end it must be something specific to my setup or environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the real issue was I am using R in jupyterlab. All I needed to do was to `print()` the string and the backslashes were removed.

Similar stacks answer: [python string adding backslash before single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052654/python-string-adding-backslash-before-single-quotes)

```
con <- RAthena::dbConnect(RAthena::athena(),
                 s3_staging_dir = s3_staging_dir)

column_values <- c("thing1","thing2","thing3")

query1 <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ({column_values*})", .con = con)
print(query1)
```

returns:

```
<SQL> SELECT COUNT (*) as venues FROM schema.table WHERE column IN ('thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3')
```